# How can I display MySQL output in Visual Basic?

Tags: mysql, basic

By output I mean for example:

```
ACTION                                     MESSAGE
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(value1,value2)   1 row(s) affected
```

I only want the output on the MESSAGE column, how can I access to MySQL output using Visual Basic?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of rows affected like this.

```
Dim numberRowsAffected As Integer
Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
Try
    'Code
    numberRowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

For more info how to use MySqlCommand object:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html

Comment: The example you provided could be the answer to his question - but his exact query was regarding capturing the exact command output - not the number of rows - maybe original questioner can clarify